# How to stop updating the parameters of a part of a layer in a CNN model (not the parameters of the whole layer)?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

For example, there are ten parameters(filters) in a CNN layer, how I can do to only update five of them and keep the rest unchanged?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Pythorch is easy to freeze only part of the net thanks to the requires_grad property:
Here is a simple script:

```
def freeze_layers(model, num_of_layers):
    freezed = 0
    for layer in model.children():
        freezed += 1
        if layer < num_of_layers:
            layer.requires_grad = False
```

Consider however that every model has a different structure and it can have leyer nested into each other, with this code you are iterating through the first level of layers in the net.
I suggest you print the layers before, to understand the network structure spefic to your case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and answers. But, I want to ask how to stop updating the parameters of a part of a layer in a CNN model, rather than the whole layer's parameters. Please pay attention to “a part of a layer's parameters”, or "only some of a layer's parameters".

Comment: what do you mean exactly with 'part of a layer'?

Comment: please check this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-stop-updating-the-parameters-of-a-part-of-a-layer-in-a-cnn-model-not-the-parameters-of-the-whole-layer/153173/3